# Why isn't my custom homepage appearing after deleting public/index.html?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to get my customized home page to appear instead of the ***Welcome Aboard** You're Riding Ruby on Rails* default page.  In my `config/routes.rb` file I have the line  `root :to => 'pages#home'` to let it load the `pages/home.html.erb` file, and I removed `public/index.html` as instructed in the comments of the routes.rb file.  All the other web pages which I used the syntax `match "/page_name", :to => "pages#page_name"` are working fine.  What more do I need to do to update my home page?

EDIT:

Someone asked me to post my pages controller.  Here it is:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @title = "Home"
  end

  def contact
    @title = "Contact"
  end

  def about
    @title = "About"
  end

  def help
    @title = "Help"
  end  
end
```

The @title variable is referred to in my .html.erb files, but otherwise my controller is pretty much empty.

Comment: So what *are* you getting when you browse to your site's root? Also, please choose more descriptive titles in the future.

Comment: I am getting the welcome aboard rails default page.  And I thought my title was punny =]

Comment: @Kvass Possibly some form of caching, there is no other place for that page to come from if you've deleted `public/index.html`. Also Stack Overflow is a reference and your question title should be informative; you get no bonus points for funny.

Comment: touche meagar :) -- and how do I stop it from caching?  any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the server after deleting index.html? Did you clear your browser cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried restarting the server after deleting index.html? Did you clear your browser cache?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a PagesController?

```
rails generate controller pages home
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax I use (Rails 2.3) is:

```
  map.root :controller => "welcome"
```

That goes to the :index method.  If you want to go to :home, I presume you would add :action.